# Error reading file: skin\comic-ui.json (Internal) Eclipse does not find file even though it exists

Tags: java, json, libgdx

For a school project we develop in a group a game, we use git in order to push and merge our codes. Yesterday we merged our codes together, our game works on everyone only I get an error.

Error reading file: skin\comic-ui.json (Internal) this is the error I am getting the file is in the asset folder but still it is not found in eclipse.`package de.unidue.angryworms.game.screens;

this is the class which uses the json file

```
  import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Event;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.EventListener;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
  import com.kotcrab.vis.ui.VisUI;
  import com.kotcrab.vis.ui.widget.VisTable;

import de.unidue.angryworms.game.SEPGame;
import de.unidue.angryworms.game.gameobjects.EnumWorld;

 public class Menu implements Screen, com.badlogic.gdx.Screen {

private SEPGame sepgame;
private Viewport menuscreen;
public Stage menustage;
OrthographicCamera camera;


public Menu(SEPGame game) {
    this.sepgame = game;


    menustage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(menustage);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    //stage.addActor(table);


/*  camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, SEPGame.V_WIDTH, SEPGame.V_HEIGHT );
    menuscreen = new FitViewport(SEPGame.V_WIDTH/2, SEPGame.V_HEIGHT/2, 
    camera);
    menustage = new Stage(menuscreen, game.batch);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(menustage);
    */


    Skin mySkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/comic-ui.json"));


    //Table table = new Table();
    //table.debug();

    //table.top();
    //table.setFillParent(true);

    //sepgame.font.getData().setScale(2, 2);






    //LabelStyle lstyle = new Label.LabelStyle(sepgame.font, Color.WHITE);
    //lstyle = mySkin;

    final Label world1nameLabel = new Label("ANGRY WORMS", mySkin);
    world1nameLabel.setFontScale(4);
    Label lbl_karte = new Label("Karte 1 - 4 auswÃ¤hlen", mySkin);
    lbl_karte.setFontScale(2);



    //TextButton button_karte = new TextButton("Karte auswÃ¤hlen",mySkin);
    TextButton button3 = new TextButton("Teams Edtitieren",mySkin);
    TextButton button_starten = new TextButton("Spiel starten",mySkin);
    final List list = new List(mySkin);
  //  MapItem[] myItems = {new MapItem("Karte1", EnumWorld.World1), new 
      MapItem("Karte2", EnumWorld.World1), new MapItem("Karte3", 
      EnumWorld.World1), new MapItem("Karte4",  EnumWorld.World1)};
    list.setItems(EnumWorld.values());

   // button2.debug();
    button_starten.addListener(new InputListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int 
        pointer, int button) {
            //world1nameLabel.setText("Pressed Text Button");
            sepgame.setScreen(new PlayScreen(sepgame, 
            (EnumWorld)list.getSelected()));
            return true;
        }
    });

    table.add(world1nameLabel).pad(50);
    table.row();
    table.add(lbl_karte);
    table.row();
    table.add(list);
    table.row();
  //  table.add(button2);
    table.row();
    table.add(button3);
    table.row();
    table.add(button_starten);

    Label lblStart = new Label("temp: press S to continue", mySkin);
    lblStart.setFontScale(3);

    table.row();
    table.add(lblStart);





    menustage.addActor(table);
    // table.addActor(world1);

    // table.setDebug(true);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render(float fval) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //camera.update();

    menustage.draw();


}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: skin/comic-ui.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:98)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:75)
    at de.unidue.angryworms.game.screens.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:62)
    at de.unidue.angryworms.game.SEPGame.create(SEPGame.java:42)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: skin/comic-ui.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:711)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: skin/comic-ui.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:78)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:709)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: skin\comic-ui.json (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:76)
    ... 7 more
```

And finally the json file

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
    button: {
        file: font-button-export.fnt
    }
    font: {
        file: font-export.fnt
    }
    title: {
        file: font-title-export.fnt
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    black: {
        r: 0
        g: 0
        b: 0
        a: 1
    }
    gray: {
        r: 0.7466668
        g: 0.7466668
        b: 0.7466668
        a: 1
    }
    white: {
        r: 1
        g: 1
        b: 1
        a: 1
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    cyan: {
        name: white
        color: {
            r: 0.30333334
            g: 0.96412176
            b: 1
            a: 1
        }
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: {
        up: button
        down: button-pressed
        over: button-highlighted
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        checkboxOn: checkbox-on
        checkboxOff: checkbox
        font: button
        fontColor: black
    }
    radio: {
        checkboxOn: radio-on
        checkboxOff: radio
        font: button
        fontColor: black
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: {
    default: {
        up: button
        down: button-pressed
        over: button-highlighted
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: {
        font: font
        fontColor: black
    }
    narration: {
        font: font
        fontColor: black
        background: narration-box
    }
    big: {
        font: button
        fontColor: black
    }
    title: {
        font: title
        fontColor: white
    }
    alt: {
        font: font
        fontColor: black
        background: window
    }
    half-tone: {
        font: button
        fontColor: black
        background: half-tone-box
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: {
        font: font
        fontColorSelected: black
        fontColorUnselected: black
        selection: cyan
    }
    select-box: {
        font: font
        fontColorSelected: black
        fontColorUnselected: black
        selection: cyan
        background: select-box-list
    }
    select-box-big: {
        font: button
        fontColorSelected: black
        fontColorUnselected: black
        selection: cyan
        background: select-box-big-list
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
    default-horizontal: {
        background: progress-bar
        knobBefore: progress-bar-knob
    }
    default-vertical: {
        background: progress-bar
        knobBefore: progress-bar-knob
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: {
        hScrollKnob: scrollbar-horizontal
        vScrollKnob: scrollbar-vertical
    }
    select-box: {
        background: select-box-list
        hScrollKnob: scrollbar-horizontal
        vScrollKnob: scrollbar-vertical
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: font
        fontColor: black
        background: select-box
        scrollStyle: default
        listStyle: select-box
        backgroundOpen: select-box-open
    }
    big: {
        font: button
        fontColor: black
        background: select-box-big
        scrollStyle: default
        listStyle: select-box-big
        backgroundOpen: select-box-big-open
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: {
        background: slider
        knob: slider-knob
    }
    default-vertical: {
        background: slider
        knob: slider-knob
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: {
        font: button
        fontColor: black
        up: button
        down: button-pressed
        over: button-highlighted
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: {
        font: font
        fontColor: black
        background: text-field
        cursor: cursor
        selection: cyan
        messageFontColor: gray
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle: {
    default: {
        label: alt
    }
    alt: {
        label: narration
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
    default: {
        plus: plus
        minus: minus
        selection: cyan
    }
}
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: {
        background: window
        titleFont: font
    }
    alt: {
        background: narration-box
        titleFont: font
    }
}
}
```

I hope someone can help me, I searched a lot but the things I found didn't help me out. The strange thing is, the same code works for my friends but not for me.

Comment: Check that you you have [gdx-skins](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins) jar in your eclipse class path. If not - try to update your eclipse project from build file (maven or grade), i.e. right click on project, select maven or grade (depending on on build script type you are using) and click 'update project'.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but what do you mean with gdx-skins jar? if I right click on my project I can select grade but the only option grade is giving me is refresh and that did not help me

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the assets folder by selecting it in the package explorer and hitting f5.